# Python specific modification of a file

Tags: python, function, file

I have a file called "data.txt" which looks like this:

```
Oliver
14052
Jack
2257
Harry
22568
Jacob
684940
Connor
46871
```

In this file the name Oliver corresponds to the number 14052, the name Jack corresponds to the number 2257, ...

I'm looking to create a function that takes two arguments: (name (str), number (int))

The function must search if the name is already in the file:

If it is there then it adds the number passed as an argument and the number corresponding to the name in the file. Then it replaces, in the file, the old figure with the result of the sum.

If it is not there then it writes at the end of the file a line with the name and one with the number, to add this new name with its number in the list.

Thank you for your attention to my question. Have a good day !

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```py
def search(name, num):
    with open('test.txt', 'r') as fp:
        data = fp.read().split("\n")
        if name in data:
            idx = data.index(name)
            data[idx + 1] = str(int(data[idx + 1]) + num)
        else:
            data += [name, str(num)]
    with open('test.txt', 'w') as fp:
        print('\n'.join(data))
        fp.write('\n'.join(data))


search('Oliver', -52)
```

Answer (score 0):

This script should be what you want :

```
file=open('name_of_your_file.txt','r')

datas=file.readlines()
file.close()


def f(name,number):

    file=open('name_of_your_file.txt','w')
    newDatas=datas[:]

    if(name+'\n' not in datas):
        newDatas.append(name+'\n')
        newDatas.append(str(number)+'\n')

    else:
        index=datas.index(name+'\n')
        newNumber=number+int(datas[index+1])
        newDatas[index+1]=str(newNumber)+'\n'

    file.writelines(newDatas)


f("Martin",15446)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
# Vote for Rusty!
def f(name, number):
    with open('data.txt') as dt:
        lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in dt]

    names = lines[::2]
    numbers = [ int(n) for n in lines[1::2] ]

    try:
        i = names.index(name)
        numbers[i] += number
    except ValueError:
        names.append(name)
        numbers.append(number)

    with open('data.txt', 'w+') as dt:
        for i in range(len(names)):
            dt.write(names[i])
            dt.write('\n')
            dt.write(str(numbers[i]))
            dt.write('\n')
```